# How can i solve the 'subprocess-exited-with-error'?

Tags: python

I encounter an error when attempting to run 'pip install -r requirements.txt', and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet git://github.com/waspinator/pycococreator.git 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-req-build-fukczz4_' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.
```

I'm working on Efficient Panoptic Segmentation on GitHub. And this it the URL: https://github.com/DeepSceneSeg/EfficientPS

Answer (score 0):

that you might have a problem with your git installation or configuration.you should check if you have git installed and added to your path env variable.you can try to use the https protocol insted of the git protocol by changing the url in your requirements.txt file.

for ex:- you can change:

```
git://github.com/waspinator/pycococreator.git
```

to:

```
https://github.com/waspinator/pycococreator.git
```

and also another one is you might need to upgrade your pip and setuptools packages to the latest version.try by running,

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

it might helps you to void some errors related to building wheels and installing dependencies as well.